# Ballon d or/Fifa the best

Tags: football, awards

Why is the final result of Golden ball or Fifa awards determined by votes and not based on statistics? Better stats show better performance eg. Messi had more goals 
and assists than Ronaldo last season at Europe. But Ronaldo won both the awards. Again chance of a goalkeeper winning these awards also seems to be very less (Buffon finishing 3rd in 2006 was the last notable one).

Answer (score 3):

Pretty simple: *What statistics?* Where do you start and where do you stop calculating? Is someone who scored more goals really the better player or did he have help?

You can't compare defenders with strikers using simple math.

- Count goals and no defender or keeper will ever win.
- Count appearances and it'll almost be mandatory to reach the CL final (or other continental tournaments) to get as many games as possible. And who plays often doesn't automatically qualify to be the best player.
- Count ratings and it will again be subjective, because they rely on human decisions.
- A keeper with most clean sheets usually has a great defense and a striker with 30 goals usually has someone with 20 assists in their team. Who decides if that striker or keeper performed great or if the team was just remarkable?

Comment: But voting also is not perfect as people can be partial.

Comment: @adithskv yes, that can happen... but unfortunately plain statistics alone cannot define who is the best player of the year. Someone who scores 10 great goals is probably a better player than someone who converted 10 rebounds and 5 penalties, although that would be 15 goals.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain how the impact factor of a player is calculated?